# Pick 9 balls from piles of different balls

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to pick nine balls from large piles of (identical) red, white, and blue balls plus one pink ball, one lavender ball, and one tan ball? What is correct answer?
Is it ${11\choose9} + {{10\choose8} * 3}$?

Comment: how many balls are there totally in the pile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

${{3}\choose{0}}{{11}\choose{9}}+{{3}\choose{1}}{{10}\choose{8}}+{{3}\choose{2}}{{9}\choose{7}}+{{3}\choose{3}}{{8}\choose{6}}$ for ways with 0, 1, 2, and 3 balls, respectively of pink, lavender, and tan colors. The idea behind ${{11}\choose{9}}$ is that to choose 9 balls from red, white, and blue balls, permute 9 identical slots and 2 identical separators and fill the three groups of slots separated with separators with red, white, and blue balls.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out before I looked a your answer. Thanks anyway though.